# Cassandra Optimistic Locking

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I have a cassandra table1:

```
CREATE TABLE Policy.table1 (
name VARCHAR ,
date TIMESTAMP ,
version_num INT,
PRIMARY KEY   (
         name
         )) WITH caching = 'all'
     --   and memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 7200 ;
     ;
```

I need to implement optimistic locking on tis table. When we read a row from table1 we remember its version_num. And when we want to update this row we compare current version_num value and value that we remembered. Also we need to increment version_num on each update.

Problems:

1. We cannot put version_num into where clause, this will create an error: Bad Request: Non PRIMARY KEY version_num found in where clause:

   ```
    update table where name = 'abc' and version = 3
   ```
2. We cannot set version_num as a part of primary key, because we need to update its value
3. If we index version_num it will not help for update statements, same exception will be thrown
4. The only way I see is to get current version_num value by Java, and if expected and actual version_num values are the same - than execute update. The problem is that in this case we have not atomic operation of checking version_num value and update the row.

Do you see any solution for this problem?

Comment: +1, good question. Picking nits - you say "I need to implement optimistic locking on tis table." But, that's not a "need" that's a solution that meets the need, that is, a particular user need. Optimistic locking over Cassandra may be a case of a relational pattern applied in a post-relational context, and there may be a post-relational pattern that serves the same purpose for the user experience. I'm looking forward to seeing whether you get some answers that are a good, natural fit for Cassandra.

Comment: So, here's a thought. What if each change was just a new row. The version number isn't stored in the row, but is just the count of rows for where name = 'blah'? Potentially uses a lot of disk, depending on how many rows you have and how many times each is updated.

Comment: You could actually store the count in a (separate) counter table. So, write to the list, bump the counter. If two writes come in, the counter still has the correct value, because the counter is bumped twice.

Comment: Given that, you just need to decide what to do with historical values of the data row. Do you need them? Then keep the log. Or do you overwrite them? That would mean less disk, and "last write wins" on the date.

Comment: Here's a description of the counter column, to clarify what I'm talking about: http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#counters

Comment: If you could, please answer the question of what you want to do with historical values = "Last one in wins"? Or do you want to block the update if someone else has also updated, like an optimistic lock normally would?

Comment: Don Branson, I would like to block the update. I have found a solution, thanks for your help. Soltion is shown in a main message of this topic.

Comment: Can you put your solution as a answer instead of as part of the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was found there: Cassandra 2.0, Lightweight transactions http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_ltwt_transaction_c.html

In case I execute query:

```
update table1 set version_num = 5 where name = 'abc'  if version_num = 4;
```

I will receive a row with `[applied]` column. This row contains boolean value: `true` = update was successful, `false` = in other case.