# Cassandra CQL UPDATE with IF

Tags: python, cassandra, cql

Newbie here (and it seems like it might be a newbie question).
Using `Ubuntu 14.04` with a fresh install of `Cassandra 2.1.1, CQL 3.2.0` (it says). 
Writing a back-end database for a **CherryPy site,** initially as a session database.

I've come up with a scheme for a kind of **'row locking'** as a session lock, but it doesn't seem to be hanging together, so I've reduced it to a simple test program running against a local **Cassandra** instance.  To run this test, I open two terminal windows to run two python instances of it at the same time, each with different instance numbers ('1' and '2').

```
import time, sys, os, cassandra
from cassandra.cluster      import Cluster
from cassandra.auth         import PlainTextAuthProvider
instance = sys.argv[1] 
cluster = Cluster( auth_provider=PlainTextAuthProvider( username='cassandra', password='cassandra'))
cdb = cluster.connect()
cdb.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS test WITH replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1}")
cdb.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.test ( id text primary key, val int, lock text )")
cdb.execute("INSERT INTO test.test (id, val, lock) VALUES ('session_id1', 0, '') ")
raw_input( '<Enter> to start ... ')

i = 0
while i < 10000:
    i += 1
    # set lock
    while True:
        r = cdb.execute( "UPDATE test.test SET lock = '%s' WHERE id = 'session_id1' IF lock = '' " % instance)
        if r[0].applied == True:
            break
    # check lock and increment val
    s0 = cdb.execute("SELECT val,lock FROM test.test WHERE id = 'session_id1' " )[0]
    if s0.lock != instance:
        print 'error: instance [%s] %s %s' % (instance, s0, r[0])
    cdb.execute( "UPDATE test.test SET val = %s WHERE id = 'session_id1'", (s0.val + 1,))        
    # clear lock
    cdb.execute( "UPDATE test.test SET lock = '' WHERE id = 'session_id1' ")        
    time.sleep( .01)
```

So if I understand correctly, the UPDATE..IF should be 'applied' (and the break taken) only if the existing value of lock is '' (an empty string), so this should give an effective exclusive lock on the row.

The problem is that the `'s1.lock != instance'` test quite frequently fires, showing that despite the UPDATE being applied, the value of lock afterwards is variously still '' or that of the other instance...

I know that when I roll out to a cluster I'm going to have to manage consistency issues, but this is against a single local Cass instance - surely consistency shouldn't be a problem here?

I can't imagine this CQL form is broken (tm), so it must be me.  What am I doing wrong, or what is it I don't understand? TIA.

**UPDATE:** Ok, I googled a lot on this before I posted here, and now have spent the day since posting doing the same.

In particular, the stackoverflow posting [Cassandra Optimistic Locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406252/cassandra-optimistic-locking) is addressing a similar issue (for a different reason), and his solution was:

```
"update table1 set version_num = 5 where name = 'abc' if version_num = 4"
```

which he says works for him - but is really exactly what I am doing, but which isn't working for me.

So I believe my approach to be sound, but clearly I have a problem.

Are there any environmental issues that could be affecting me? (installation, pythonic, whatever...)

Answer (score 0):

**Unsatisfactory Work-Around found***

After trying a lot of variations of the test code (above), I have come to the view that the statement:

```
    "UPDATE test.test SET lock = '%s' WHERE id = 'session_id1' IF lock = '' "
```

around 5% of the time it finds lock is '' (empty string), it actually **fails** to write the value to lock, but nevertheless returns 'applied=True'.

By way of further testing, I modified that test code as follows:

```
    # set lock
    while True:
        r = cdb.execute( "UPDATE test.test SET lock = '%s' WHERE id = 'session_id1' IF lock = '' " % instance)
        if r[0].applied == True:
            s = cdb.execute("SELECT lock FROM test.test WHERE id = 'session_id1' " )
            if s[0].lock == instance:
                break
     # check lock and increment val
     (etc)
```

... so this code now confirms that the lock had been applied, and if not, it goes back to try again...

So this is:

```
1) Horrible
2) Kludgy
3) Inefficient
4) Totally reliable (the only thing that really matters to me)
```

I've tested this on the 'single local Cassandra instance', and the main point is that the incrementing of the 'val' column that the lock is supposed to be protecting, does reach the proper terminating value (20000 with the code as above).

I've also tested it on a 2-node cluster with a replication factor of 2, with one instance of the test code running on each node, and that works too (although the "UPDATE ... IF" statement, now with a consistency of QUORUM, occasionally returns:

```
exception - code=1100 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses]\
    message="Operation timed out - received only 1 responses." \
    info={'received_responses': 1, 'required_responses': 2, 'write_type': 5, 'consistency': 8}
```

... that needs careful handling, as it appears that the lock has **always** been set, despite not having received all of the replies... and it cannot be retried, as the operation isn't idempotent...)

So I clearly haven't fixed the underlying problem, and although I have fixed the symptom, I would still appreciate a more thorough insight into what is happening...

I'd appreciate any feedback (but at least I can make progress again).  TIA

Comment: I know this is a very old post, and I unfortunately haven't tested this myself, but the simplicity is that with a mechanism like this where your update is guaranteed atomicity with a specific syntax - you need to do that with EVERY statement you execute.  You can't do "UPDATE .. SET ... IF ..." and then run a statement right after it with no " ... IF ..." part - because something else may have changed it since.  Again I haven't tested, but from what I can tell, that is the source of the issues you describe.

Answer (score 0):

So I've had some communication with Tyler Hobbs (Datastax), and in a nutshell:

"The correct functioning of the mechanism that provides the atomic test-and-set facility (via LightWeight Transactions) depends upon using the same mechanism to clear the lock."

... so I need to use a similar 'IF' construct to clear it, even though I already know the contents...

```
# clear lock
cdb.execute( "UPDATE test.test SET lock = '' WHERE id = 'session_id1' IF lock = '%s'" % instance)
```

... and that works.