# How to enable optimistic locking (versioning) in Cassandra using Spring-Data?

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

The answer [Cassandra Optimistic Locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406252/cassandra-optimistic-locking) but the question describes that Optimistic Locking (versioning) exists in Cassandra.

My question is how to do it in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lightweight transactions in Cassandra Spring Data are supported via [InsertOptions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/InsertOptions.html) class or [UpdateOptions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/UpdateOptions.html) - you create an instance of it via corresponding builder, for example, [InsertOptions.InsertOptionsBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/InsertOptions.InsertOptionsBuilder.html), and then pass instance of it to the corresponding operation `insert` or `update`.

Result of operation is obtained from instance of WriteResult class that is returned by `insert`/`update` by calling the [.wasApplied function](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/WriteResult.html#wasApplied--).

More detailed information could be found in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#cassandra.template.insert-update).